# Alt Gr key not working after Ubuntu 18.04 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, keyboard

I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 from a 16.xx version and have found that I can't use Alt Gr key anymore.

I tried to find *alternate keys* in Settings but there is no clue of it.

Does anybody now how to fix it?